# What is the best way to create a multi-language (country) website in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to create a project with multi-language (country) like **EN-US**, **EN-UK**, **ZH-CN**. The EN-US and EN-UK site will have the same content with the different being the currency but for the ZH-CN site which is a site of China user, it would have a different content such as the footer will not have social media links (like facebook, twitter, youtube given that this service are block in china).

Each website will have the ability to which between two or three languages like the EN-US site, users will be able to switch between English and Spanish. I know how to do this switching between languages.

What i currently do not know how to do is creating the routes and how to output different content. Like do i hard code the routes, as in manually write out **/en-us**, **/en-uk**, **/zh-cn** into the routes.php file and each route output different content.

**Hard Coding the Routes and Output the Views (Just an Example)**

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'mysite.local'], function() {
    Route::get('/en-us', function() {
        return view('english.home');
    });
    Route::get('/zh-cn', function() {
        return view('chinese.home');
    });
});
```

Does anyone know a better way to create this type of site. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks You

Comment: Have a look at the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/localization

Comment: @Daan That is not what i want, as i mentioned above i know how to switching between languages. tks for the reply

Comment: You're asking how to create the routes, well they do mention it in the docs.

Comment: @Daan but can you show me an example of how to do it, a short and simple one will do. I just need an concept and visual on how it works. Like how do i output different content based on different country site. thanks you

Comment: I used: https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization  Which helped me out with multi-language applications / websites.

Comment: @Duikboot I tried this is plugins before what it does is pretty much translation where what i want is outputting different views for different locale. Anyway thanks you for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

I did something really similar and it worked great.
Heres a quick snippet of my multidomain L4 APP

**app/Http/routes.php**

```
use App\Domain;

Route::bind('tld', function($value, $route)
{
    $project = $route->getParameter('projectSlug');
    if($project->tld !== $value)
        App::abort(404);
    return $value;
});
Route::bind('projectSlug', function($value, $route)
{
    return Domain::where('slug', '=', $value)->firstOrFail();
});
// routes.php
Route::group(['domain' => '{projectSlug}.{tld}'], function($projectSlug)
{
    Route::get('/', [ 'as' => 'index.index', 'uses' => 'Frontend\ReportsController@index' ]);
});
```

And in your Controller you can do something like:

```
public function index($projectSlug) {
...
$domain = Domain::findorFail($projectSlug->id);
..
return view('domain.view', compact('domain'));
..
```

Each Domain with its name is saved in the database. Now if a user access the site, laravel is looking for this domain. Et voila - you have a multi Domain Laravel Application :)